# How do you pass a JSON list to a new API request?

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I am trying to request from Twitch's API a list of live streamers.

First, I need to check all streamers from a specific Twitch Team, which the API gives me their IDs. Then, I need to check which are live right now. For this, I have written the following code:

```
import requests
import json
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


response = requests.get("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/teams/rhynoesports",
                        headers={'Accept': 'application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json',
                                 'Client-ID': 'KEY'})

ids = []

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    for i in response.json()["users"]:
        uid = i["_id"]
        ids.append(uid)

parameters = {
    "channel": ids
}

response_live = requests.get("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/",
                             params=parameters,
                             headers={'Accept': 'application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json',
                                      'Client-ID': 'KEY'})


status = []

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    for s in response_live.json()["streams"]:
        sid = s["channel"]["display_name"]
        sviewer = s["viewers"]
        sgame = s["preview"]["medium"]
        status.append(sid)
        status.append(sviewer)
        status.append(sgame)

print(status)
```

The first request to the API, appends this to `ids` the following:

```
['151725719', '45737168', '156113210', '89293605', '650627666', '136014647',
 '99060924', '246849290', '61610474', '602283265', '204979621', '507115885',
 '49251436', '265876002', '155784200']
```

How can I use the `ids` stored to be used as the parameters for the `channel` request?

Answer (score 0):

```
https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams?user_id=123&user_id=456 230
```

You can use this API to see if the stream ID has a payload or not

You’ll get returns for only live streams.

Comment: I know that. What I want to do is pass the list of fetched IDs from the first API call, to the parameters of the second API call.